# NSPredicate: to-Many relationship with date iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

I am working on core data relationships and came across one complex situation.
I am having two entities say **Customers** and **Orders**.

One customer may order multiple items. So, it's to-Many relationship from customer to order.

[image]

**Query :** Fetch all the customers who haven not ordered since a month.

What's the optimum way to get the result with core data?

---

**Update :**

Tried with this predicate :

```
NSPredicate *newPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ANY custOrders.treatDate <= %@", endDate];
```

Actually It gives me the result that if customer has ordered a month ago or not..
If it has ordered again then also it returns the result.
I just want the result with customers who haven't ordered since a month.. !!!

Comment: assuming you mean more optimum than fetching all customers where custOrders.treatData is older than a month?

Comment: That makes sense since you need to find the MAX date not just any date

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your predicate is incorrect; searching for `@"ANY custOrders.treatDate <= %@"` will return the customers having **ANY** orders taking place within the time period provided. What you want to do is find the customer whose maximum order date was less than a month ago.

One of the nifty, lesser known features on Core Data is that you can query using the foundation collection operators like max, min and sum.

This should work:

```
NSPredicate *p = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"custOrders.@max.treatDate <= %@", endDate];
```

Comment: One more question : How can I get the "customers" whose birthdays are in this month? Core data saves the `NSDate` in form of `timeInterval`... !!!

Comment: then you need to find the start of the month and the end of the month and search for all dates in that range. Alternatively, you could save their birthday as several attributes, month, day, year and then you could query that way :)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use a reversed predicate:

```
NSPredicate *notFilter = [NSCompoundPredicate notPredicateWithSubpredicate:filter];
```